# Change margins for one item in a beamer slide

Tags: beamer, equations, margins

You can see that the equation is cut off at the right side of the slide.
Can I reduce left margin only for this item?

[image]

```
\begin{frame}{Conditional Hazard Ratio under Competing Risks}
\begin{itemize}
\item Competing Risks: 
\item $ h(t) = h_1(t) + h_2(t) $
\item $ \theta_{k_1,k_2}(t_1,t_2) = \dfrac{h_{1,k_1}(t_1|T_2 = t_2, K_2 = k_2)}{h_{1,k_1}(t_1|T_2>t_2)} $

 \begin{equation}
 \dfrac{ \Pr(T_{1a}-T_{1b})(T_{2a}-T_{2b}) > 0 | (T_{1ab} = t_1, T_{2ab} = t_2), (K_{1ab},K_{2ab}) = (k_1,k_2)}{ \Pr(T_{1a}-T_{1b})(T_{2a}-T_{2b}) < 0 | (T_{1ab} = t_1, T_{2ab} = t_2), (K_{1ab},K_{2ab}) = (k_1,k_2)} 
\end{equation}

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your equation is wider than text width ... so you need to make shorter or locally enlarge horizontal space for it. If this still not gives satisfactory result, use of smaller fonts may help. In MWE below are considered both measures:

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{changepage}
\makeatletter
    \newsavebox\restorebox
\newenvironment{restoretext}%
    {\@parboxrestore% 
     \begin{adjustwidth}{-8mm}{-8mm}%
                \begin{lrbox}{\restorebox}%
                \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
    }{\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}
        \usebox\restorebox
        \end{adjustwidth}
     }
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Conditional Hazard Ratio under Competing Risks}
\begin{itemize}
\item Competing Risks:
\item $ h(t) = h_1(t) + h_2(t) $
\item $ \theta_{k_1,k_2}(t_1,t_2) = \dfrac{h_{1,k_1}(t_1|T_2 = t_2, K_2 = k_2)}{h_{1,k_1}(t_1|T_2>t_2)} $
\begin{restoretext}\small
\begin{equation}
 \dfrac{ \Pr(T_{1a}-T_{1b})(T_{2a}-T_{2b}) > 0 | (T_{1ab} = t_1, T_{2ab} = t_2), (K_{1ab},K_{2ab}) = (k_1,k_2)}{ \Pr(T_{1a}-T_{1b})(T_{2a}-T_{2b}) < 0 | (T_{1ab} = t_1, T_{2ab} = t_2), (K_{1ab},K_{2ab}) = (k_1,k_2)}
\end{equation}
\end{restoretext}
\item item 
\item item

\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

By defined box `restoretext` is first restored text width in list environment to `\textwidth` and than with `adjustwidth` macro from package `changepage` enlarged for 8 mm on each side. With this and reducing font size to `\small` the equation can be fitted into Beamer frame.